# Flutter app shows a black screen before loading the app

Tags: flutter

I have noticed this problem with flutter apps, when I open a flutter app from cold boot, I see a black screen popping before the actual app is loaded. I have seen the problem with the Newsvoice production app and as well as with a test app I installed.

Check the video here: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zszud6UWzps`

Is it a bug in the Flutter SDK?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue was [fixed recently](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/3956). If you are using a version of Flutter that has this engine fix, you won't see the black frame. (The fix should be on the Flutter `master` branch by now, but not the `alpha` branch.)

Answer (score 5):

It's not issue, this for hot reload. Don't worry about that. When you run with release, you can't see this.

if you want to be sure try ->

flutter run --release

Comment: May be you should not start your answer with 'It's not issue' because it totally is, only in debug mode though. The release mode part is helpful

Comment: For me it is other way, it is not showing on the debug mode but shows when i put the app on test flight

Answer (score 3):

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
    android:resource="@drawable/my_splash"
    />
```

AndroidManifest.xml check the FlutterActivity and add this code

Comment: what's `my_splash`?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug. That's the way it behaves normally. You can replace the loading black screen with an image:

In AndroidManifest.xml, here is where you can change your splash image.

```
       <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" 
android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
```

Find the files:

android\app\src\main\res\drawable\launch_background.xml

android\app\src\main\res\drawable-v21\launch_background.xml

Change the files to add your own custom image:

```
<item>
    <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/splash_image" />
</item>
```

Your splash image should be stored in the drawable folders:

android\app\src\main\res\drawable\splash_image.png

app\src\main\res\drawable-v21\splash_image.png

Comment: This Worked for me. But, I had to remove 'android:gravity="center" ' for a perfect render.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this issue, after removing FutureBuilder when using Firebase. just initialize Firebase app on `main()` like this

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

instead of using FutureBuilder on your build method

Answer (score 0):

The black screen is something which comes for a variety of reasons is what I have gathered from looking at different responses on the net. In my case I realized on thing, that my Firebase.initializeApp() was returning an error in the snapshot of my FutureBuilder due to which no widgets were being rendered. I tried everything to no avail. Finally I moved my project to a completely new folder as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67743041/firebase-initialization-error-on-flutter-missingpluginexception)

and then my black screen issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, it is an actual splash screen. to replace that black/white screen you can refer to this [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

or

**1. Run this command on terminal**

```
flutter pub add flutter_native_splash
```

This will add a line like this to your package's `pubspec.yaml` and run an implicit flutter pub get:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19
```

**2. How to set the splash screen**

in your project's `pubspec.yaml` file, after `dev_dependencies` add..

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#FFA500" 
  image: assets/logo.png  // you need to have an image in the assets folder
  android: true
  ios: true
```

**3. Run the package**

run the following command in terminal

```
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

this will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make shure you built a release apk with

```
flutter build apk
```

When you run the generated apk the issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

check your json file at your asset, in my case I put an invalid json file like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on your main page and adjust the seconds as per your needs:

```
void main() async {
  print(DateTime.now());
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {});
  FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this approach over the previous nine answers? (Are you sure this hasn’t been suggested previously?) Please explain.