# flutter showing black screen in first running application

Tags: flutter

[this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45827533) couldn't solve my problem

after switching flutter channel to `master` and upgrading flutter this problem don't resolve on my applications. how can i solve that?

```
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.22.0-10.0.pre.139, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.450], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0-10.0.pre.139 at F:\software\flutter
    • Framework revision 3dfbdac6f4 (3 hours ago), 2020-09-11 11:40:03 -0400
    • Engine revision 983b0ef164
    • Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-116.0.dev)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    • Android SDK at F:\software\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = F:\software\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 49.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • WAS LX1A (mobile) • 2XJDU17C14006203 • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)
```

content of new flutter application:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Android `style.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`launch_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
     <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="instaluxury"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
        android:value="true" />
</application>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this problem is on all of `flutter` build version and regarding this issue our problem solved by this code:

```kotlin
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityLaunchConfigs
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityLaunchConfigs.BackgroundMode
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    }

    override fun getBackgroundMode(): FlutterActivityLaunchConfigs.BackgroundMode {
        return BackgroundMode.transparent
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here for someone of the future:
I was also running a flutter demo for the first time and i had no idea on why my Android Studio emulator was just showing a black screen.

Turns out I had to click the power button lol