# Firebase initialization error on flutter MissingPluginException

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am developing an app in flutter I am using firebase in this app. And I am using following dependencies:

```
firebase_messaging: ^10.0.0
firebase_core: ^1.2.0
cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0
firebase_storage: ^8.1.0
```

I am initializing firebase like this:

```
void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
runApp(MyApp());
}
```

This whole code was working fine till today's morning but after that it is giving this error everytime:

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53273/b_8_mVgWJY0=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
I/flutter (15902): completed
E/flutter (15902): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled  Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method  Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)
E/flutter (15902): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (15902): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15902): #1      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:344:35)
E/flutter (15902): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15902): #2      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:30:23)
E/flutter (15902): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15902): #3      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:77:7)
E/flutter (15902): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15902): #4      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:41:31)
E/flutter (15902): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15902):
```

Is there anything wrong with android studio or flutter SDK itself? I have also noticed that there is one file generated that was not there earlier when the app was working fully functional the file is named "generated_plugin_registrant.dart".

**Update**:
I removed flutter from my windows and again installed it but it didn't work as well. Now I think I should uninstall android studio completely and again install it because I don't find any error or wrong implementation in my code till now, Please tell me if there is any.

Please help me.

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched a lot on the internet but the solution was very simple. It was happening because the following code was missing in my **MainActivity.kt**.
Code:

`override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {`
`GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine); }`

It was not registering the flutter plugins that's why it was giving an error it took me 2 and a half days I hope if someone else is facing this issue they can solve it earlier than me.

And thanks for all your replies.

Comment: Where add this code?Can you show full code?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I also tried many solution like you, but could not able to resolve it issues.

Latter, I ended up creating a new project carefully copying firebase and multiple other packages from the original project. After that I copied every single file in lib/android along with their respective configurations in build.gradle and manifests. For iOS I just copied the entire project and that worked immediately.

You also can try like my. Create a new project and copy everything from your old project to new one, one by one to see this issue resolved or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

in the terminal and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have tried it as well as flutter pup cache repair, it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running flutter clean in the terminal?

```
flutter clean
```

and then

```
flutter pub get
```

edit:

Or,
in `android/build.gradle` under `dependencies`, you could use another version of gradle build tools if it helps

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have tried it as well as flutter pup cache repair, it didn't worked.

Comment: Have you tried setting minifyEnabled and shrinkResources to false in buildTypes?

Comment: or have you tried using other methods to initialize it? as it's mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63492262/7015400

Comment: or does it help to use another version of gradle build tools? I'll edit my answer and put the line there.

Comment: I have tried changing initialization methods also I have tried with different Gradle build tools and plugins nothing changed, And I have added shrink resources and minifyEnabled to false as well that also didn't work. However, I noticed some warnings so I am updating the question please check it once.

Comment: Is there by any chance that android studio or flutter sdk has got some problem?