# Flutter - Intermittent black screen on reopening app

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I've noticed this now quite a few times in my app, specifically on Android - when re-opening the app after some time, it just opens to a completely black screen, and doesn't load.

I can't reproduce the issue by force-closing and reopening, or just closing and re-opening, it just seems to happen at random, especially after leaving the app unused for some time.

I've looked at the log-cat logs and there's absolutely nothing there at all.

The app runs a sql-lite database and reloads all data on a complete re-load, but otherwise just uses an in app data model and ignores sql-lite, however this happens so frequently it cannot be after a background app kill.

I haven't seen this issue in dev mode, or release mode, only after compiling to an APK or App Bundle. I have tried with --no-shrink to disable R8 & proguard with no difference.

The app needs to be killed, then re-opened to launch properly.

I'm running:

Flutter 1.22.6 • channel unknown • unknown source

Framework • revision 9b2d32b605 (8 months ago) • 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -080

Engine • revision 2f0af37152

Tools • Dart 2.10.5

Upgrading to Flutter 2 is not an option at present because of some of my dependencies.

Has anyone got any idea what this might be? I'm at a loss so far.

Comment: Check This : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827533/flutter-app-shows-a-black-screen-before-loading-the-app

Comment: Did you set a [splash screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen) to your app?

Comment: I have not put on a splash screen, however this issue only occurs intermittently, and when the app is already loaded, not when it's starting up - at that point there is no loading screen. I have been able to replicate it simply by minimising then re-opening the application

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue? If yes then please let me know. I'm also facing this issue.